# Append items that weren't removed into separate list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know how to append all the items that weren't removed into a new list.

```
challenge = [1, 0, 9, 8, 5, 4, 1, 9, 3, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9]

def remove_values(thelist, value):
    newlist = []
    while value in thelist:
        thelist.remove(value)
        newlist.append()

bye = remove_values(challenge, max(challenge))
```

For example, if I remove all the 9s (the max), how do I append the rest into a new list?

Comment: `return [x for x in thelist if x != value]` ? Or is there a deeper reason to mutate `thelist`?

Comment: try with a for loop

Comment: If you must mutate the original list, you could do `for idx,item in enumerate(thelist): if item == value: newlist.append(thelist.pop(idx))`, the `pop()` call is O(n) though each time

Answer (score 0):

```
challenge = [1, 0, 9, 8, 5, 4, 1, 9, 3, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9]

# This will append every item to a new List where the value not is max
# You won't need 2 lists to achieve what you want, it can be done with a simple list comprehension
removed_list = [x for x in challenge if x != max(challenge)]
print(removed_list)
# will print [1, 0, 8, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```